# SPJobDefinition not recognized

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace SeaforthCalendar.TimerJob
{
    class SeaforthSyncTimer : SPJobDefinition
    {
        public SeaforthSyncTimer() { }

        public override void Execute() 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have added Microsoft.SharePoint to references.  Why isn't SPJobDefinition recognized?

Comment: Make sure you added the correct Microsoft.SharePoint.dll reference (not the client one) and also make sure your solution is not set to Sandboxed